# Angular change active nav-link on scroll

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I'm currently working on an one-pager with a nav by bootstrap. Since I don't know a way to scroll to certain div's ids with `routerLink`, I'm using `href=#id`, which works fine so far. I'm currently trying that onWindowScroll the class `active` shall swap it owner according to the current div which is displayed.

**So when the user for instance scrolls to `about`, the `active` class shall be assigned to the associated `nav-link`, which in this case obviously is `about us`.**

```
@HostListener('document:scroll', [])
  onWindowScroll() {

  }
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="nav-link logo float-left" href="#">peak design</a>
  <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our work</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: How to get the marked function in my question above working.

Comment: In bootstrap search for `Scrollspy`